# Does Google ignore empty tags?

Tags: seo, google-search, html, technical-seo

In my source code, I have two H1 tags. The first is used for my page title and the second is in not populated: `(<h1></h1>)`

Does Google read this as an H1 tag still, or will it ignore this tag completely and only read one H1 on the page?

Comment: Do the empty tags serve a purpose?  If they are useless, you should remove them regardless of how Google treats them.

Answer (score 1):

If you can remove the empty H1 is better, but nothing to worry as google pick the overall intent of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Google will typically ignore empty header tags. Google has also confirmed or has been cited as saying that using multiple header tags or H1s is completely fine and will not impact, help or hurt, how you rank.
https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-h1-headings-seo/328459/#close

Answer (score -2):

As long as one tag is empty you will only have one h1 tag and this is fine. 2 h1 tags will only confuse the search engines.
But the title is the title and h1 is h1. So don't use h1 as page title, for title use title tag.